# how band read array just return me 0, how can i do?

Tags: gdal, landsat

I am new in GDAL. I use landsat image in classification but I apply these code line band data just give me 0, what I don't understand:

```
raster_dataset = gdal.Open(‘LC81850552017065LGN00_B3.tif’, gdal.GA_ReadOnly) 
geo_transform = raster_dataset.GetGeoTransform() 
proj = raster_dataset.GetProjectionRef() 
bands_data = [] 

for b in range(1, raster_dataset.RasterCount+1): 
    band = raster_dataset.GetRasterBand(b) 
    bands_data.append(band.ReadAsArray())
    bands_data = np.dstack(bands_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `bands_data` from a list to a numpy array, which is causing your trouble. Perform the `np.dstack` operation after all bands have been read in (after the loop has been completed).

See the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to better understand how `dstack` works.